# tensorflow : embedding_ops : SafeEmbeddingLookupSparseTest, test case need explaination?

Tags: tensorflow, embedding

Trying to do some features engineering with 
`from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers import embedding_ops`, going through it's unittest, do some printing , finding https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.0.1/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/embedding_ops_test.py#L69, then read this comments https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.0.1/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/embedding_ops.py#L57, Is there anyone know why these id weights have to be non negative ? What is the purpose of pruning negative weight ? 
Is this some common machine learning practice or some design choice? Please, help me, thanks. my tensorflow version is v1.0.1